# Altium - Do Schematic Variables Exists?

Tags: altium, variable

In Altium Designer (v.16.0), I would like to assign several resistors with the value "R", and being able to change them only by assigning the value of R to e.g. 10k, at some place of the application.

I've been unable to seek this on internet nor in the tutorials, i always got with the Parameter concept, which are the standards values specifying the components. I am thinking on general values, like global variables, or local variables per Schematic, so you can use them as in a design stage, eventually using operations such as R/2 or 2R, etc.

Comment: You can assign all of these resistors to a Class, then use Find Similar Objects to select them all and change their properties all at once.

Comment: If you are ok with scripting in Delphi or VB you can create a post processing script that will put this effect in your BOM, not your schematic though. Essentially you would parse each components Value field that you populate with R*x then apply your scalar to the same field. I cannot think of a way for altium to do this for you in the schematic apart from variants, but that's still not quite what you are asking for.

Comment: I am actually wanting to do this for the simulation stage. The running VB could change the value of components at my command. It is an interesting alternative......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they do.  They are called "parameters" just like parameters associated with components (e.g. Designator, Name, Value, etc.), except you define them either at the Project level or the Document (schematic) level.

For project, go to Project -> Project Options -> Parameters tab.
For document, have nothing selected and open the Properties dialog -> Parameter tab.

To use them, set the Value of your component to "=ParamName" (without the quotes).

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/workspacemanager-dlg-projectpropertiesdialog-pagecontrol-main-parametersproject-options-parameters-ad

Comment: This is the behavior I was expecting to find. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe Altium supports this kind of parameterized behavior. As Photon suggested, you can add them to a class or take some other kind of action that will allow you to select them, or use the assembly variant functionality to swap between different value configurations-- but you'll have to assign the part changes individually in each variant.

If you have the components in a database, you could change the value in the database and update the components, but that is probably going to be messy.

Comment: Is it possible to define such variables as Spice code into the AdvancedSim Generated Netlists?. Because those files are generated, i think it is not possible to introduce Spice script into there...

Comment: @hyprfrcb I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: I found it is possible to define parameters, just like the `.PARAM` SPICE command, which indeed works exactly like that. It is found under Simulation>Global Parameters.